# How to pull values from firebase instead of hard code

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I am building a profile page in flutter and am wondering what the best way to simply replace the hard coded values with values pulled from firestore. Does anyone have any recommendations on how best to do this?

Did not find the tutorial useful.

I am trying to replace the below numeric values with values pulled from firestore.

```
new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    rowCell(343, 'POSTS'),
                    rowCell(673826, 'FOLLOWERS'),
                    rowCell(275, 'FOLLOWING'),
                  ],),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to pass the user Id to the a widget that returns the profile. for example

```
    class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    final String userId;
    ProfileWidget (this.userId);
          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(userId)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
              return Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        rowCell(user.posts, 'POSTS'),
                        rowCell(user.followers, 'FOLLOWERS'),
                        rowCell(user.following, 'FOLLOWING'),
                      ],),

                      },
          );},}
```

now the user class :

```
class User{
  final int following;
  final int posts;
  final int followers;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : following = map['following'],
        posts = map['posts'],
        followers= map['followers'];

  User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

Comment: thanks, salma! i have done so, but am getting an error for the rowCell function. I really only have to pull the 'name' value from firestore for now. Do you have any thoughts on what could be going wrong?